# spring security: "The page isn’t redirecting properly" post request requires authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want POST-requests to an endpoint to require authentication, whereas everybody is allowed to send GET requests.

The page loads normally, when I make a POST request by submitting a form, I get redirected to /login, but my browser returns the following error message instead of the login page:

> "The page isn’t redirecting properly Firefox has detected that the
> server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will
> never complete."

Here is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin((form) -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll())
                .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Added trace logs. The following log snippet is printed multiple times

```
2023-06-11T19:52:29.216+02:00 DEBUG 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/error?continue to session
2023-06-11T19:52:29.216+02:00 DEBUG 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
2023-06-11T19:52:29.223+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@53a8f4e9, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@15422a19, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@76f6e7dc, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6266f443, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@7b9949d5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@5643446e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@1aeae61, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@38f16850, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@2339b850, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@853667b, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@85228bf, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@59989298]] (1/1)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.223+02:00 DEBUG 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2023-06-11T19:52:29.223+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.224+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.224+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.224+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.224+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (5/12)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.224+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS]
2023-06-11T19:52:29.224+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/12)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.224+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2023-06-11T19:52:29.224+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (7/12)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.224+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/login', POST]
2023-06-11T19:52:29.224+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (8/12)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.224+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
2023-06-11T19:52:29.224+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (9/12)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.224+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (10/12)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.224+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (11/12)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.224+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (12/12)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.224+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@6cbaba3]
2023-06-11T19:52:29.224+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@6cbaba3] using org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer$$Lambda$1311/0x000000080182f790@75242932
2023-06-11T19:52:29.224+02:00 DEBUG 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2023-06-11T19:52:29.226+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2023-06-11T19:52:29.226+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession D693E6FFD13D0E76F70DB0BF2756DD6D using the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT session attribute
2023-06-11T19:52:29.226+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-06-11T19:52:29.226+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-06-11T19:52:29.226+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=D693E6FFD13D0E76F70DB0BF2756DD6D], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2023-06-11T19:52:29.226+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@53a8f4e9, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@15422a19, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@76f6e7dc, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6266f443, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@7b9949d5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@5643446e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@1aeae61, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@38f16850, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@2339b850, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@853667b, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@85228bf, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@59989298]] (1/1)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.226+02:00 DEBUG 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2023-06-11T19:52:29.226+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.226+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.226+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.226+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.226+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (5/12)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.226+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/12)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.227+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2023-06-11T19:52:29.227+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (7/12)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.227+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/login', POST]
2023-06-11T19:52:29.227+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (8/12)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.227+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
2023-06-11T19:52:29.227+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (9/12)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.227+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (10/12)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.227+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (11/12)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.227+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (12/12)
2023-06-11T19:52:29.227+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@7b35a637]]
2023-06-11T19:52:29.227+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@7b35a637]] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@7134bdf1
2023-06-11T19:52:29.227+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession D693E6FFD13D0E76F70DB0BF2756DD6D using the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT session attribute
2023-06-11T19:52:29.227+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-06-11T19:52:29.227+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-06-11T19:52:29.227+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=D693E6FFD13D0E76F70DB0BF2756DD6D], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2023-06-11T19:52:29.227+02:00 TRACE 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=D693E6FFD13D0E76F70DB0BF2756DD6D], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:238) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:225) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:238) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:225) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:238) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:225) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:238) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:225) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:238) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:225) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:238) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:225) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:238) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:225) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:238) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:225) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:238) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:225) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:238) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:225) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:238) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:225) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:238) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:321) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:222) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:642) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:277) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:358) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:222) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623) ~[na:na]

2023-06-11T19:52:29.228+02:00 DEBUG 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/error?continue to session
2023-06-11T19:52:29.228+02:00 DEBUG 5674 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
```

Comment: enable spring security trace logs and post them here